# Form Validation for dynamic added fields in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I've created a reactive form with multiple input fields. The validation works fine for one field but I stuck for the validation on my dynamic added input fields.

What I want to achieve is that for every row the both input fields should be required too. The problem must be the access of the formarray.

[image]

I created a simplified version on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7bhkku)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing the form array input control is not correct way. I updated the stackblitz. Refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3cym5a